# Register an ExceptionMapper in Jersey 2.10.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, jersey-2.0, grizzly

By default, Jersey is broken. It shows exceptions neither in the returned HTML nor in the log file. Due to deployment constraints I cannot use the XML registration mechanism for Jersey resources, and am doing it programatically. The following has no effect:

```
@Provider
public class ExceptionDump implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException ex) {
        String trace = Exceptions.getStackTraceAsString(ex);
        return Response.status(500).entity(trace).type("text/plain").build();
    }
}

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> cls = new HashSet<Class<?>>(super.getClasses());
        cls.add(ExceptionDump.class);
        return cls;
    }
    ...
}
```

The Grizzly container loads and runs, but the exception mapper is ignored and Grizzly still only shows "Request failed." on errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "the XML registration mechanism"? The web.xml file?

Comment: Yes, web.xml. I've actually got this working now - I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by using a (much) higher class than `WebApplicationException`, such as `Throwable`. Simply, there are exceptions that are thrown that do not inherit from `WebApplicationException`, so it's wrong for most of the examples on the web to show `WebApplicationException` without the caveat that many internal errors will go unreported unless a more general parent is used.

Comment: So what about the programmatic set-up? How did you do it?

Comment: implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>